# RxJava flat map: what happens when one of the resulting observable complete?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava, I know flatmaps are for mapping an emitted item to observable. I also know that based on the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) the emitted observables all get combined (flatten) to a single observable stream.

I was wondering what happens if any of those inner observables get completed?

for example: I have an observable that emits a item data key. I have to make another async http call to get the item data from the server, so I call it by using another observable. I use a flat map to connect these two and create one main observable.

When does the run() method of following "SomeMethodThatWantsItems" get called?

```
public void someMethodThatWantsItems(MyHttpCaller httpCaller, SomeSearchEngine searchEngine)
{
    Consumer<Item> onNextConsumer = 
    Observable<Item> searchObservable = getSearchResult(httpCaller, searchEngine, "The Search Word");
    searchObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Item>(){
                           @Override
                           public void accept(@NonNull Item item) throws Exception {
                               //Do stuff with the item
                           }
                       }
                , new Consumer<Exception>() { //some implementation of onErrorConsumer
                    }
                 //OnComplete
                , new Action(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() throws Exception {
                            //When does this get called??? after the search complete or when the first http call is successful? 
                        }
                    });

}

private Observable<String> getSearchResultKeys(SomeSearchEngine searchEngine, String someSearchWord)
{
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull final ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {

            //Assume that our search engine call onFind everytime it finds something
            searchEngine.addSearchListener(new searchEngineResultListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFind(String foundItemKey){
                    emitter.onNext(foundItemKey);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinishedFindingResults(){
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

private Observable<Item> getItemByKey(MyHttpCaller httpCaller, String key)
{

    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Item>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull final ObservableEmitter<Item> emitter) throws Exception {

            //Call the server to get the item
            httpCaller.call(key, new onCompleteListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCompletedCall(Item result)
                {
                    emitter.onNext(result);
                    //The result is complete! end the stream
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public Observable<Item> getSearchResult(MyHttpCaller httpCaller, SomeSearchEngine searchEngine, String someSearchWord){
    //Where everything comes together
    Observable<String> searchResultObservable = getSearchResultKeys(searchEngine, someSearchWord);
    retuern searchResultObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .flatMap(new Function<String, Observable<Item>>(){
                @Override
                public Observable<Item> apply(String key){
                    return getItemByKey(httpCaller, key);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onComplete()` always get call once and then the streams stops. (this is part of the [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)).
That means that in your case, your `onComplete()` at `SomeMethodThatWantsItems` will be called after **all** items were retrieved.
In case of `flatMap()`, completion of each inner `Observable`, simply will signal the source `Observable` to stop flatting item from the inner `Observable` to the source `Observable`, `flatMap()` merges items from the inner `Observable` as long as this stream sends items, so it's basically consume the entire inner `Observable` stream into the source stream, the entire stream is until termination event3 like `onComplete()`, so in case where inner `Observable` can emit more than 1 item,  that means that it will make more than 1 emission on the source stream.